# Visual Studio for Mac Preview unable to connect to Android debugger

Tags: android, .net, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-2022

I am attempting to debug a Xamarin.Forms application on an Android device (a recent Samsung Galaxy, but noted on other devices as well). When I build and launch the application from Visual Studio for Mac (preview 17.0 build 6509), I get the message "Could not connect to the debugger." In the Application Output window, I can see this message (in addition to others):

```
[monodroid-debug] Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8853,server=y,embedding=1
```

The looking at the device logcat messages, I see:

```
2022-02-14 13:01:24.052 7973-7973/? E/adbd: failed to connect to socket 'tcp:8853': Connection refused
```

This made it seem like the port was closed by the macOS firewall, but it seems to be open:

```
❯ nmap -p 8853 localhost
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-02-14 13:04 CST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00020s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1

PORT     STATE SERVICE
8853/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.07 seconds
```

Each time the debugger launches, it increments the port by one. It's possible these ports aren't opened until after the debugger closes, but I'm not aware of a way to know that for certain.

How can I connect a debugger from Visual Studio for Mac to an Android device? I've seen this issue on both an M1 and Intel macOS laptop.

Comment: Before debugging can occur on a device, it must be setup for development and connected to your PC or Mac. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development

Comment: I've done plenty of Android debugging in a variety of environments. I have the Android SDK configured on my device. The device is physically connected. This has been noted by other developers, and seems to be a new issue with the debugger in Visual Studio Preview 2022.

Comment: In this case, you can create a new simple project and test,if it dont work,you could post an issue on visual studio .